# check json array is empty using prototype

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, prototype

in mybb forum with ajax call i get json array as result.

php code:

```
<?php
define("IN_MYBB", 1);
define('THIS_SCRIPT', 'getComuni.php');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
....read data form DB
$comuni = array();

while($row = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
    $comuni[$row['ID']] = $row['Descrizione'];
}
echo json_encode($comuni);
?>
```

Javascript:

```
function showComuniCompleted(response)
{
    var json = response.responseJSON;
    for(var k in json)
    {
     $("cboComuni").insert(new Element("option", {value: k}).update(json[k]));
    }      
}
```

json variable is Object not Array when empty get error in for istruction.
Is there a way to convert json variable from Object to Array or some way to check if empty?

Comment: why not `update(json.k)` ? it could work

Comment: Are you receiving the JSON in the JavaScript as a string? If so you need to parse the JSON or test the string length to determine emptiness.

Comment: have you parsed your `json` variable, using something like `JSON.parse()` ?

Comment: In modern browsers (IE9 >), you can do `Object.keys(json).length === 0` to check for empty object.

Comment: Object.keys(json).length === 0 works for me